# Update value of variable when append is limited to one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to update the value of appended list item after every click. The value is from a select option, after every click it appends the value to ***ul***. My problem is I only needed to append the value 1 time so the other appended value is not shown. It should just update the already appended value.

```
var standard = 0;
var n_standard = 0;
function standardRoom() {
    n_standard = n_standard + Number($("#selectBoxStandard").val());
    standard++
    if (standard <= 1 ) {
        $("#roomDetail ul").append('<li class="hr">Number of room(s): '+ n_standard +'</li>');
    }
}

<label for="rooms" style="color:black">No. of rooms: </label>
  <select required tabindex="10" id="selectBoxStandard" name="n_rooms"> 
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
  </select>

<div  class="button-style-1" style="padding-bottom:80px" style="padding-bottom:40px"><a href="javascript:standardRoom()" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span class="mobile-visibility">BOOK</span></a></div>

<div id="roomDetail">
  <ul class="tabs">

   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried html instead of append keyword?

Comment: It does not make sense to make a dynamic list of only one item. So just include the output HTML already and replace the append function with a function that updates the output instead. Each room could have their own details , so you want a list of rooms, not a list of details.

Comment: by `value` you mean the `innerHTML`?

Comment: you want to add the new `<select>` to be added to the previos `<select>` value?

Comment: My bad... That is correct, i should have used .html and use different div for each room

Comment: You could also clear the list befor appending: `$("#roomDetail ul").empty().append('<li class="hr">Number of room(s): '+ n_standard +'</li>')`. But i go with Shilly - updating the node feels better then removing it and adding a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `append` use `.html` and when click `function` is invoked mark the `counter(standard)` to 0 after every function call so as to print again. When it is not given value of 0 on every click it's value will increment and you will always get the result ones

```js
var standard = 0;
var n_standard = 0;
function standardRoom() {
    n_standard = n_standard + Number($("#selectBoxStandard").val());
    standard++
    if (standard <= 1 ) {
        $("#roomDetail ul").html('<li class="hr">Number of room(s): '+ n_standard +'</li>')
        standard=0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="rooms" style="color:black">No. of rooms: </label>
  <select required tabindex="10" id="selectBoxStandard" name="n_rooms"> 
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
  </select>

<div  class="button-style-1" style="padding-bottom:80px" style="padding-bottom:40px"><a href="javascript:standardRoom()" ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span class="mobile-visibility">BOOK</span></a></div>

<div id="roomDetail">
  <ul class="tabs">

   </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add text inside the last `<li>` in the list, you can use:

```
let items = document.querySelectorAll("ul.tabs > li");
items[items.length - 1].innerHTML += "add this text";
```